# Error "req.body.fileToString is not a function"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, fs, multer

Working with nodejs and mongodb file upload
This is my **POST API**

```
router.post('/create',multer({ storage : storage}).any(), (req, res) => {
    var sample = fs.readFileSync('./uploads/'+req.files[0].filename,'utf8');

    var tc = new Testcase({
        name: req.body.name,
        upload: req.files[0].filename ,
        run: req.body.fileToString(function() {
            let arr = sample.split(/\r?\n/);
        arr.forEach((step , idx)=> {
        if(step.includes("step")){
        console.log(step);
        return step;
        }
        });
        }
        ), 
        modify: req.body.modify,
        delete: req.body.delete,
        step1: req.body.step1,
        step2: req.body.step2,
        step3: req.body.step3,
        step4: req.body.step4,
        step5: req.body.step5,
        step6: req.body.step6,
        step7: req.body.step7,
    });
    
    
    console.log(req.files[0].filename);
    tc.save((err, doc) => {
        if (err) { res.status(401).send("error") }
        else { 
            res.status(200).send(doc)
        }
    });
});
```

When I use postman to Post a new row with a file I get this error:

"message": "req.body.fileToString is not a function"

What Am I doing wrong please

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong:

```
run: req.body.fileToString(function() {
        let arr = sample.split(/\r?\n/);
    arr.forEach((step , idx)=> {
    if(step.includes("step")){
    console.log(step);
    return step;
    }
    });
```

you can't send parameters to `req.body.fileToString` because it is data from client and not a function

Comment: Do you have a solution on how to store the result of the function inside the variable 'run'??

Comment: I can't understand what do you want to do

Comment: I'm uploading a file to my database using multer, Im trying to make a function that reads the file i'm upoading, search for the lines that include the word 'step' and store the result into the variable 'run', the function fileToString is functional and it gives me what I want.. I want to store the result of the function inside the variable when I create a new row

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code into this

```
router.post('/create',multer({ storage : storage}).any(), (req, res) => {
    var sample = fs.readFileSync('./uploads/'+req.files[0].filename,'utf8');
    var stepss = function(callback) {
        let arr = sample.split(/\r?\n/);
        arr.forEach((step , idx)=> {
        if(step.includes("step")){
        console.log(step);
        stepstr = JSON.stringify(step);
        callback(null, stepstr);

        }
    });
     }
     
    
    var tc = new Testcase({
        name: req.body.name,
        //upload: url + "/uploads/" + req.files[0].filename ,
        upload: req.files[0].filename ,
        run: stepss,
        modify: req.body.modify,
        delete: req.body.delete,
        step1: req.body.step1,
        step2: req.body.step2,
        step3: req.body.step3,
        step4: req.body.step4,
        step5: req.body.step5,
        step6: req.body.step6,
        step7: req.body.step7,
    });
    
    //const file = req.file;
    console.log(req.files[0].filename);
    tc.save((err, doc) => {
        if (err) { res.status(401).send("error") }
        else { 
            res.status(200).send(doc)
        }
    });
});
```

But now when I add something the content of the variable run is exactly the function I wrote but not the result of it :

```
"run": "function(callback) {\r\n        let arr = sample.split(/\\r?\\n/);\r\n        arr.forEach((step , idx)=> {\r\n        if(step.includes(\"step\")){\r\n        console.log(step);\r\n        stepstr = JSON.stringify(step);\r\n        callback(null, stepstr);\r\n\r\n        }\r\n    });\r\n     }",
```

How do I store return value of the function into a variable?